# Dash to Panel GNOME extension not functioning on Fedora 36

Tags: fedora, gnome

I am trying to follow the tutorial [here](https://ostechnix.com/how-to-enable-minimize-and-maximize-buttons-in-fedora/) to add a Windows-like taskbar to the bottom of my screen in Fedora 36.

I successfully installed GNOME Tweaks and the maximize and minimize windows, but when I to the Dash to Panel page on GNOME Extensions, it does not allow me to toggle it on:

[image]

Any solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Run this to your terminal:

```
gnome-extensions-app
```

It will ask you to install if it is not yet installed, and will run if already installed. A dialog box will popup. Turn on the extension and go back to the `gnome-extensions.org` site. You should be able to toggle it on.

[image]